# Vue: login validation not working in my code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating login validation in Vue.js but the error message is not displaying and it gives me the error:

> Property or method "error" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Any help?

Template:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container" width="900">
    <div class="row justify-content-center"  style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <div class="col-5">
        <div v-if="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          {{error}}
        </div>
        <div class="card" >
          <div class="card-text">
            <div class="form-group" @keyup.enter="logItIn">
              <input class="form-control"
              v-model="login.email"
              label="Email"
              placeholder="Email Address"
              required
              >   <br>
              <input class="form-control"
              v-model="login.password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  @click='logItIn'>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```javascript
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        email:"",
        password:"",
        error: ""
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async logItIn() {
      try {
        axios.post('https://odevin-api.herokuapp.com/login',this.login)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let newToken=response.data.response.token;
            window.token=newToken;
            let user=response.data.response.user;   //response
            localStorage.setItem('token',newToken);
            localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
            window.axios.defaults.params={api_token:newToken}
            // Event.$emit('login',user);
            this.$router.push('/');
          });
      } catch(e) {
        this.error = 'invalid user name or password';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using it as `error` but you defined it as `login.error`.  Maybe you meant to move it outside of the `login` object in `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you referenced `{{ error }}` in your template but in your data object, `error` is a property of login object. so vue can't find it properly.

either change the usage in your template to `{{ login.error }}` or define it in your data object like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    error: '',
    login: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: i treid this but  now it doesn't show the error message i set "invalid user name or password"

Comment: So you are passed the error in your question, now you have to check if the `error` is updated correctly or not! did you change the template binding or the data object?

Comment: the data object

Comment: I think there might be some issue with `logItIn` function, you used `async` keyword but I can't see any `await` keyword in it! I doubt this is the right syntax, maybe catch block doesn't get to run at all. read this link maybe it helps (only the first part that describes a login function in vue using `async ... await` syntax), also you can put a `console.log` in the catch block to see if it runs or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343792/vue-login-function/65344571#65344571